# Multi-threaded consumer configuration in RabbitMQ server using spring amqp?

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, consumer, spring-amqp

We are implementing RabbitMQ using Spring-AMQP and our requirement is to run consumer in multiple threads to consume messages from single queue.  Is there any server(RabbitMQ) side scripting need to be done or any other ways we can run the multiple threads at consumer level for single queue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I guess, it is your answer:

```
<rabbit:listener-container id="container1" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="manual" concurrency="5">
    <rabbit:listener id="testListener" queue-names="foo, #{bar.name}" ref="testBean" method="handle"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Pay attention to the **concurrency** attribute.
[Here is a manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#containerAttributes)

Comment: Thanks Bilan for the reply! came to know  from the forums where  concurrency attribute is not recommonded when dealing with large set of data. Whether we can go for it or not?

Comment: Point me out, please, where you have seen it. I'd recommend to play with it in your environment and maybe there is no any reason to use concurrency at all...